# VueJS and Ant Design - update input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I am really new to Vue.js and have a question.

What I want to achieve is:

-Have two input fields. If you type in something in the first input field, the value of the second input field should be updated with the value of the first input but base64 encoded.

Here is what I have tried:

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import Antd from "ant-design-vue";
import "ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css";

Vue.use(Antd);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    tokenInput: null,
    tokenOutput: null,
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange: function() {
      this.tokenOutput = btoa(this.tokenInput);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

App.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Home/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Home
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Home.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>helloworld</h1>
    <a-tabs default-active-key="1">
      <a-tab-pane key="1" tab="token converter">
        <div class="content">
          <a-card title="Input" class="token">
            <a-textarea
              v-model="tokenInput"
              @change="handleChange"
              allowClear
              placeholder="Input the token to convert ..."
              :rows="20"
            >
            </a-textarea>
          </a-card>
            <a-card title="Converted token:" class="token">
            <a-textarea
              :value="convertedToken"
              disabled
              :rows="20"
            />
          </a-card>
        </div>
      </a-tab-pane>
      <a-tab-pane key="2" tab="2nd tab"> Nothing is here. </a-tab-pane>
    </a-tabs>
  </div>
</template>


<style>
.content {
  padding: 24px;
}
.token {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

The error message I get:

***Property or method "handleChange" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property***

I have also tried:

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return {
              tokenInput: null,
              tokenOutput: null,
     }
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange() {
      this.tokenOutput = btoa(this.tokenInput);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

What am I doing wrong ?